# AppStore: In-App-Purchases: Real-time Developer Notifications

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

I'm developing an app which has in-app-purchases with Subscriptions (the user can buy a monthly/yearly subscription).
How do I get my back-end get notified about subscription-related actions (new/cancelled/renewed/etc)?

I did find how to do it with Google PlayStore:
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html#realtime-notifications
The In-app Billing API provides server push notifications that give developers the capability to monitor state changes for Play-managed subscriptions. To enable this capability, you will need to integrate your backend with Cloud Pub/Sub using your own Google Cloud Platform (GCP) project, and fill in Google Play Console the Pub/Sub topic to which Play should publish notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution:

Look for "Status Update Notifications" in https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html

Quoting the relevant part (in case the URL will be removed):

> A statusUpdateNotification is a server-to-server notification service
>   for auto-renewable subscriptions. A notification specifies the status
>   of a subscription at the time the notification is sent.
>
> To obtain up-to-date information as you process events, your app
>   should verify the latest receipt with the App Store. It is recommended
>   that you use the status update notification service along with receipt
>   validation to validate a user’s current subscription status and
>   provide them with service. See Receipt Validation Programming Guide
>   for information about receipt validation.
>
> To receive status update notifications, configure a subscription
>   status URL for your app in iTunes Connect. The App Store will deliver
>   JSON objects via an HTTP POST to your server for the key subscription
>   events listed in Table 6-3. Your server is responsible for parsing,
>   interpreting, and responding to all statusUpdateNotification posts.
>
> Note: Using the server-to-server notification service is optional. You
>   can opt in at any time.
>
> The statusUpdateNotification is an HTTP POST. The body of the POST
>   contains the data elements listed in the Table 6-3...